# Installing Frama-c Sodium/Fluorine in Ubuntu 14.04 from source

Tags: frama-c

I'm trying to install frama-c from source code in my Ubuntu 14.04 but it's never possible.

Fluorine make error:

```
allberson@allberson-Aspire-E1-531:~/Área de Trabalho/frama-c-Fluorine-20130601$ make

Generating   src/lib/dynlink_common_interface.ml
Generating   src/kernel/config.ml
Generating   ptests/ptests_config.ml
Generating   share/Makefile.kernel
Generating   .depend
Ocamlc       src/lib/dynlink_common_interface.cmo
Ocamlc       src/kernel/config.cmo
Ocamlc       src/ai/abstract_interp.cmi
File "src/ai/abstract_interp.mli", line 166, characters 4-33:
Error: In this `with' constraint, the new definition of O
       does not match its original definition in the constrained signature:
       ...
       The field `find' is required but not provided
make: ** [src/ai/abstract_interp.cmi] Erro 2
```

Sodium make error:

```
Makefile:2456: aviso: ignorando comandos antigos para o alvo `de'
Ocamlopt     src/gui/property_navigator.cmx
ocamlopt.opt: don't know what to do with de.
Usage: ocamlopt <options> <files>
Options are:
  -ffast-math  Inline trigonometric and exponential functions
  -a  Build a library
  -absname  Show absolute filenames in error messages
  -annot  Save information in <filename>.annot
  -bin-annot  Save typedtree in <filename>.cmt
  -c  Compile only (do not link)
  -cc <command>  Use <command> as the C compiler and linker
  -cclib <opt>  Pass option <opt> to the C linker
  -ccopt <opt>  Pass option <opt> to the C compiler and linker
  -compact  Optimize code size rather than speed
  -config  Print configuration values and exit
  -dtypes  (deprecated) same as -annot
  -for-pack <ident>  Generate code that can later be `packed' with
     ocamlopt -pack -o <ident>.cmx
  -g  Record debugging information for exception backtrace
  -i  Print inferred interface
  -I <dir>  Add <dir> to the list of include directories
  -impl <file>  Compile <file> as a .ml file
  -inline <n>  Set aggressiveness of inlining to <n>
  -intf <file>  Compile <file> as a .mli file
  -intf-suffix <string>  Suffix for interface files (default: .mli)
  -labels  Use commuting label mode
  -linkall  Link all modules, even unused ones
  -no-app-funct  Deactivate applicative functors
  -noassert  Do not compile assertion checks
  -noautolink  Do not automatically link C libraries specified in .cmxa files
  -nodynlink  Enable optimizations for code that will not be dynlinked
  -nolabels  Ignore non-optional labels in types
  -nostdlib  Do not add default directory to the list of include directories
  -o <file>  Set output file name to <file>
  -output-obj  Output a C object file instead of an executable
  -p  Compile and link with profiling support for "gprof"
     (not supported on all platforms)
  -pack  Package the given .cmx files into one .cmx
  -pp <command>  Pipe sources through preprocessor <command>
  -ppx <command>  Pipe abstract syntax trees through preprocessor <command>
  -principal  Check principality of type inference
  -rectypes  Allow arbitrary recursive types
  -runtime-variant <str>  Use the <str> variant of the run-time system
  -S  Keep intermediate assembly file
  -shared  Produce a dynlinkable plugin
  -short-paths  Shorten paths in types
  -strict-sequence  Left-hand part of a sequence must have type unit
  -thread  Generate code that supports the system threads library
  -unsafe  Do not compile bounds checking on array and string access
  -v  Print compiler version and location of standard library and exit
  -verbose  Print calls to external commands
  -version  Print version and exit
  -vnum  Print version number and exit
  -w <list>  Enable or disable warnings according to <list>:
        +<spec>   enable warnings in <spec>
        -<spec>   disable warnings in <spec>
        @<spec>   enable warnings in <spec> and treat them as errors
     <spec> can be:
        <num>             a single warning number
        <num1>..<num2>    a range of consecutive warning numbers
        <letter>          a predefined set
     default setting is "+a-4-6-7-9-27-29-32..39-41..42-44-45"
  -warn-error <list>  Enable or disable error status for warnings according
     to <list>.  See option -w for the syntax of <list>.
     Default setting is "-a"
  -warn-help  Show description of warning numbers
  -where  Print location of standard library and exit
  -nopervasives  (undocumented)
  -dsource  (undocumented)
  -dparsetree  (undocumented)
  -dtypedtree  (undocumented)
  -drawlambda  (undocumented)
  -dlambda  (undocumented)
  -dclambda  (undocumented)
  -dcmm  (undocumented)
  -dsel  (undocumented)
  -dcombine  (undocumented)
  -dlive  (undocumented)
  -dspill  (undocumented)
  -dsplit  (undocumented)
  -dinterf  (undocumented)
  -dprefer  (undocumented)
  -dalloc  (undocumented)
  -dreload  (undocumented)
  -dscheduling  (undocumented)
  -dlinear  (undocumented)
  -dstartup  (undocumented)
  - <file>  Treat <file> as a file name (even if it starts with `-')
  -help  Display this list of options
  --help  Display this list of options
make: ** [src/gui/property_navigator.cmx] Erro 2
```

Comment: Could you post the error you obtain when compiling Sodium with `LC_ALL=C VERBOSEMAKE=yes make` (`LC_ALL` is not necessary, but you might get better answers with `make` warnings in English rather than in Portuguese)? Also, note that the preferred way of installing Frama-C is through `opam` (https://opam.ocaml.org)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, this error stems from a too recent version of OCaml. You should try with OCaml 3.10.2, or better, with a new version of Frama-C. Sodium, which was just released, fixes this issue. Also, as mentioned by Virgile, the simplest would be to use the Opam package.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved it. I installed frama-c/why using opam (4.01.0). But now I'm running frama-c with jessie and there is this error:

```
$ frama-c -jessie copy.c
[kernel] Parsing FRAMAC_SHARE/libc/__fc_builtin_for_normalization.i (no preprocessing)
[kernel] Parsing copy.c (with preprocessing)
[jessie] Starting Jessie translation
[jessie] Producing Jessie files in subdir copy.jessie
[jessie] File copy.jessie/copy.jc written.
[jessie] File copy.jessie/copy.cloc written.
[jessie] Calling Jessie tool in subdir copy.jessie
Generating Why function copy
[jessie] Calling VCs generator.
why3 ide  --extra-config /home/hpe/.opam/4.01.0/lib/why/why3/why3.conf copy.mlw
[Config] reading extra configuration file /home/hpe/.opam/4.01.0/lib/why/why3/why3.conf
/usr/local/lib/why3/plugins/genequlin can't be loaded : Dynlink error : error loading shared library: /usr/local/lib/why3/plugins/genequlin.cmxs: undefined symbol: camlWhy3__Term__t_app_4489
/usr/local/lib/why3/plugins/tptp can't be loaded : Dynlink error : error loading shared library: /usr/local/lib/why3/plugins/tptp.cmxs: undefined symbol: camlWhy3__Pp__print_list_1023
/usr/local/lib/why3/plugins/hypothesis_selection can't be loaded : Dynlink error : error loading shared library: /usr/local/lib/why3/plugins/hypothesis_selection.cmxs: undefined symbol: camlWhy3__Pp__print_list_1023
[GUI] Init the GTK interface... done.
[GUI config] reading icons... done.
[GUI] Creating tree model... done
[GUI] found regular file 'copy.mlw'
[GUI] using 'copy' as directory for the project
[GUI session] Opening session...

[GUI session] Opening session: update done

[GUI session] Opening session: done
[GUI session] Adding file '../copy.mlw'
[GUI] adding file ../copy.mlw in database
Error while reading file '../copy.mlw':
File "/home/hpe/.opam/4.01.0/lib/why/why3/jessie_why3.mlw", line 268, characters 13-27:
unbound symbol 'Double.div_post'
make: ** [why3ide] Erro 1
[jessie] user error: Jessie subprocess failed: make -f copy.makefile why3ide
```